# Why does one of two identical REST requests work and not the other?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, https, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I have these two little controllers:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[RoutePrefix("api/Org")]
public class OrgController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Organization>> Get()
    {
        Db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return await Db.Organizations.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

and

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[RoutePrefix("/api/Branch")]
public class BranchController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Branch>> Get()
    {

        Db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return await Db.Branches.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

And I call them like this, respectively, using a `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsync("/api/Org", null, cancellation);
```

and

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsync("/api/Branch", null, cancellation);
```

When I request Orgs, I have a successful request that returns 4 Orgs, but when I request Branches, I get a response with **HTTP 405 - Method not allowed**. Now I know I'm using POST to make requests to `Get` methods, but sometime long ago I learned that it was for some reason more secure, and it normally works fine.

The main point here is that this proven pattern has always worked for me, and does work for all other such controllers and POST requests in the entire app. What could make just the the request for `"/api/Branch"` fail?

**UPDATE:** I changed the action method signature to look like this, and it works fine now:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Get")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Branch>> Fetch()
```

This is strange, because POST requests work directly to the `Get` actions on all the other controllers, as long as the `HttpPost` attribute is present. My problem is worked around, but this question remains open as to why. Contrary to Jinish's answer, the `/` at the start of the route prefix seems to make no difference. Some controllers had it, some didn't, and they all worked, except for `BranchController`.

Comment: You were missing the `[Route]` attribute, so what was actually happening was that it defaulted back to convention-based routing. `[Route("")]` would work for both actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymousAttribute` instead of `System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymousAttribute`. Using modern conveniences, when I added the attribute, I was prompted (I think by ReSharper, but maybe by VS itself) to import a namespace for it. In my haste I failed to notice their were two namespaces as options and I chose the wrong one. The correction is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
//using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe your [RoutePrefix] can start with a '/'
It should be [RoutePrefix("api/Branch")]

Comment: Tried removing the `/` and I still get exactly the same behaviour, but, when I changed the action name, and aliased it to `Get`, things started working fine. See my edit above please.